# using a local image on webpage using alias HTML

Tags: html, apache, alias

I have been trying to get an image to display on my website, the image is located in my documents

```
/home/pi/Documents/test/testImage.jpg
```

I have already created an alias inside my `alias.conf` file.  It looks like this...

```
Alias /MyTest/ "/home/pi/Documents/test/"

<Directory "/home/pi/Documents/test/">
Options FollowSymlinks
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When i go on a remote computer and type `http://myIPAddress/MyTest/testImage.jpg` it successfully displays the image.

However, when I try to create a webpage which contains this image I have no success accessing it remotely.

My code looks like

```
<html>
<body>
<img src="http://myIPAddress/MyTest/testImage.jpg" alt="test" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
</body>
</html>
```

This code works when i try accessing it from my server but as soon as i use a remote computer the image does not show up.

Any help is greatly appreciated as this issue is really stumping me

Thank you everyone for the help